# RegExp infinite loop only in perl, why?

Tags: regex, perl, loops, path, regex-group

I have a regular expression to test whether a CSV cell contains a correct file path:

**EDIT** The CSV lists filepaths that does not yet exists when script runs (I cannot use -e), and filepath can include * or %variable% or {$variable}.

```
my $FILENAME_REGEXP = '^(|"|""")(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/])?[\\\/]{0,2}(?:(?:[\w\s\.\*-]+|\{\$\w+}|%\w+%)[\\\/]{0,2})*\1$';
```

Since CSV cells sometimes contains wrappers of double quotes, and sometimes the filename itself needs to be wrapped by double quotes, I made this grouping (|"|""") ... \1

Then using this function:

```
sub ValidateUNCPath{
    my $input = shift;
    if ($input !~ /$FILENAME_REGEXP/){
        return;
    } 
    else{
        return "This is a Valid File Path.";
    }

}
```

I'm trying to test if this phrase is matching my regexp (It should not match):

```
"""c:\my\dir\lord"
```

but my dear Perl gets into infinite loop when:

```
ValidateUNCPath('"""c:\my\dir\lord"');
```

**EDIT** actually it loops on this:

```
ValidateUNCPath('"""\aaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbb\ccccccc\Netwxn00.map"');
```

I made sure in http://regexpal.com that my regexp correctly catches those non-symmetric """ ... " wrapping double quotes, but Perl got his own mind :(

I even tried the /g and /o flags in

```
/$FILENAME_REGEXP/go
```

but it still hangs. What am I missing ?

Comment: There is no code you have posted that can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: instead of return; try return "";

Comment: The syntax `if (...) return; else return;` would cause a syntax error in perl... why don't you paste your *real* code, including the loop you are using, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks TLP - I cleaned non-relevant lines, now the { } are fixed.

Comment: @NoamManos You have not yet pasted in the code that shows the infinite loop.

Comment: 0_0  Why not use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) to grab the fields in each line and then test the file path with [`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)?

Comment: If the file paths might not exist at runtime, then how do you know that a file path is "valid"?  In other words, explain what you're trying to accomplish with your regex.

Comment: @Noam Manos - It endlessly backtracks because of this [\w\s\.\*-]`+` get rid of the `+` quantifier.

Comment: There's _got_ to be a better way to do what you want.. What's a "valid" path? Is it files that exist or strings is a legal path on Windows? Believe either problem can be solved a lot easier..

Comment: @Jack Maney - Text::CSV is not in perl default bundle, it's a CPAN module, and my script runs on multiple build machines, so I cant constantly update their perl installations...

Comment: Who said anything about updating a Perl installation?  All you have to do is have the module installed on each machine.  Or, even easier, you can set up a NFS with [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib) on it.

Answer (score 3):

First off, nothing you have posted can cause an infinite loop, so if you're getting one, its not from this part of the code.

When I try out your subroutine, it returns true for all sorts of strings that are far from looking like paths, for example:

```
.....
This is a Valid File Path.
.*.*
This is a Valid File Path.
-
This is a Valid File Path.
```

This is because your regex is rather loose.

```
^(|"|""")                  # can match the empty string
(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/])?       # same, matches 0-1 times
[\\\/]{0,2}                # same, matches 0-2 times
(?:(?:[\w\s\.\*-]+|\{\$\w+}|%\w+%)[\\\/]?)+\1$  # only this is not optional
```

Since only the last part actually have to match anything, you are allowing all kinds of strings, mainly in the first character class: `[\w\s\.\*-]`

In my personal opinion, when you start relying on regexes that look like yours, you're doing something wrong. Unless you're skilled at regexes, and hope noone who isn't will ever be forced to fix it.

Why don't you just remove the quotes? Also, if this path exists in your system, there is a much easier way to check if it is valid: [`-e $path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: All of your tests are of perfectly valid relative file paths, so they don't show that the regex is broken.

Comment: @RobKennedy I don't think any string comprised of `[\w\s\.\*-]+` is a valid path.

Comment: Each of your tests fits that regex, and each of your tests is a valid relative path.

Comment: @RobKennedy How's these examples?

Comment: @TLP hmmm, yes the script should allow both full paths and relative paths. But I still don't understand why it takes ages for perl to calculate the regexp. Please try this phrase - my perl hangs on it:
**ValidateUNCPath('"""\aaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbb\ccccccc\Netwxn00.map"');**

Comment: @NoamManos Wow, that is weird.. never seen a regex hang before. Don't have time to analyze it now, but I'll bet its because you have the empty string possibility in the first parethesis, and `\1` causing infinite backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Edit: From trial and error, the below grouping sub-expression `[\w\s.*-]+` is causing backtrack problem

```
    (?:
        (?:
             [\w\s.*-]+
          |  \{\$\w+\}
          |  %\w+%
        )
        [\\\/]?
    )+
```

Fix #1, 
Unrolled method

```
'
 ^
    (                          # Nothing
      |"                       # Or, "
      |"""                     # Or, """
    )
                      # Here to end, there is no provision for quotes (")
    (?:               # If there are no balanced quotes, this will fail !!
        [a-zA-Z]
        :
        [\\\/]
    )?
    [\\\/]{0,2}

    (?:
        [\w\s.*-]
      |  \{\$\w+\}
      |  %\w+%
    )+
    (?:
        [\\\/]
        (?:
            [\w\s.*-]
          |  \{\$\w+\}
          |  %\w+%
        )+
    )*
    [\\\/]?
    \1
 $
'
```

Fix #2, Independent Sub-Expression

```
'
 ^
    (                          # Nothing
      |"                       # Or, "
      |"""                     # Or, """
    )
                      # Here to end, there is no provision for quotes (")
    (?:               # If there are no balanced quotes, this will fail !!
        [a-zA-Z]
        :
        [\\\/]
    )?
    [\\\/]{0,2}

    (?>
       (?:
           (?:
                [\w\s.*-]+
             |  \{\$\w+\}
             |  %\w+%
           )
           [\\\/]?
       )+
    )
    \1
 $
'
```

Fix #3, remove the + quantifier (or add +?)

```
'
 ^
    (                          # Nothing
      |"                       # Or, "
      |"""                     # Or, """
    )
                      # Here to end, there is no provision for quotes (")
    (?:               # If there are no balanced quotes, this will fail !!
        [a-zA-Z]
        :
        [\\\/]
    )?
    [\\\/]{0,2}

    (?:
        (?:
             [\w\s.*-] 
          |  \{\$\w+\}
          |  %\w+%
        )
        [\\\/]?
    )+
    \1
 $
'
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want - to fail on non-symmetric quotes. But the problem is that it takes ages for perl to calculate the regexp. Please try this phrase - my perl hangs on it: **ValidateUNCPath('"""\aaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbb\ccccccc\Netwxn00.map"'); **

Comment: @Noam Manos - Ok, I see the problem. Posted an Update with a fix.

Comment: Thanks! you found the loop cause, though I don't understand why RegExPal.com worked, but Perl hanged before... Also what does ?> in fix #2 do ?

Comment: `(?>)` is an Atomic Grouping. Its the same as a possesive quantifier except its applied as a group instead of a quantifer. The problem you are having is on FAIL and having nested quantifers. IE: `(?:(?:[]+)+`. Your regex had just too many backtrack permutations on FAIL. Read up on the affects of nested quantifiers. The possesive expression your regex needs is something like this `'^(|"|""")(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/])?[\\\/]{0,2}(?:(?:[\w\s.*-]++|\{\$\w+\}|%\w+%)[\\\/]?)+\1$'`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the regex engine was naïve,

```
('y') x 20 =~ /^.*.*.*.*.*x/
```

would take a very long time to fail since it has to try

```
20 * 20 * 20 * 20 * 20 = 3,200,000 possible matches.
```

Your pattern has a similar structure, meaning it has many components match wide range of substrings of your input.

Now, Perl's regex engine is *highly* optimised, and far far from naïve. In the above pattern, it will start by looking for `x`, and exit very very fast. Unfortunately, it doesn't or can't similarly optimise your pattern.

Your patterns is a complete mess. I'm not going to even try to guess what it's suppose to match. You will find that this problem will solve itself once you switch to a correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sln this is my fixed regexp:

```
my $FILENAME_REGEXP = '^(|"|""")(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/])?[\\\/]{0,2}(?:(?:[\w\s.-]++|\{\$\w+\}|%\w+%)[\\\/]{0,2})*\*?[\w.-]*\1$';
```

(I also disallowed * char in directories, and only allowed single * in (last) filename)

Comment: You should be able to significantly speed that up using `'^(|"|""")(?:[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/])?[\\\/]{0,2}(?:(?:[\w\s.-]++|\{\$\w+\}|%\w+%)[\\\/]{0,2})*\*?[\w.-]*\1$'` This merges the overlap, and adds Possesive quantifier `++` (same as atomic `(?>)` grouping) that was causing nested quantifier catastropic backtracking on the old regex. In the smallest sense, instead of `(?:(?:[\w\s.-]))*`, `(?:(?:[\w\s.-]++))*` on FAIL, will fail immediatly rather than backtrack and consume quickly rather than 1 character at a time.

Comment: Thanks @sln - on my local perl it works great now! (Regexpal.com doesn't accept it however....) - I'm modifying my last answer as you suggested.